# GeoHistogram does not plot all data when points are spaced out

Tags: plotting, bugs, geodesy

`GeoHistogram` appears to be leaving out some of the data given to it.  A minimal example follows.

```
SeedRandom[4123];
dOne = MultinormalDistribution[{-45, 90}, {{15^2, 1}, {1, 30^2}}];
dTwo = MultinormalDistribution[{45, -90}, {{15^2, 1}, {1, 30^2}}];

dsTest = <|"GeoPosition" -> GeoPosition@#|> & /@ RandomVariate[dOne, 200] // Dataset;
```

`dsTest` holds points close enough together for `GeoHistogram` to plot all of them.

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, Point@GeoPosition[Identity @@@ Normal@dsTest[All, "GeoPosition"]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GeoHistogram[Normal@dsTest[All, "GeoPosition"], Quantity[500, "Kilometers"], 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.8]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when a few points are added further away from this set of points some of them are not plotted by `GeoHistogram`.

```
dsTest = Join[dsTest, <|"GeoPosition" -> GeoPosition@#|> & /@ 
    RandomVariate[dTwo, 5] // Dataset];

GeoGraphics[{Red, Point@GeoPosition[Identity @@@ Normal@dsTest[All, "GeoPosition"]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GeoHistogram[Normal@dsTest[All, "GeoPosition"], Quantity[500, "Kilometers"], 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.8]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The points on the right-hand side in the Pacific Ocean and in North America are not plotted.

Ideas?

## Update

Actually it is worse that I thought. It seems `GeoHistogram` only considers a region in the neighborhood of the first point. Consider the following.

Start with a few points on one area and then add a lot of points a distance away.

```
dsTest = <|"GeoPosition" -> GeoPosition@#|> & /@ RandomVariate[dOne, 5] // Dataset;
dsTest = Join[dsTest, <|"GeoPosition" -> GeoPosition@#|> & /@ 
    RandomVariate[dTwo, 200] // Dataset];
```

Then

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, Point@GeoPosition[Identity @@@ Normal@dsTest[All, "GeoPosition"]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GeoHistogram[Normal@dsTest[All, "GeoPosition"], Quantity[500, "Kilometers"], 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.8]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here it can be seen that only the area near to the first point (near Australia) is considered.  The massive number of points in North America are not plotted.

**Update** Confirmed bug CASE:3725237

Comment: It's a glitch in the `GeoRange`, try `Graphics[lastPlot[[1, 1]]]` where `lastPlot` is your last example to see what I mean.

Comment: Workaround: `ReleaseHold["OriginalInput" /. (Method /. Options[lastPlot, Method])]`

Comment: Still very broken if I need to it be on a certain `GeoCenter`. Eg. `GeoHistogram[Normal@dsTest[All, "GeoPosition"], 
 Quantity[500, "Kilometers"], PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.8]}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", GeoCenter -> {-45, 130},
 ImageSize -> Large]` on the second definition of `dsTest`

Comment: The workaround works for me even with that example.

Comment: I think it could be an issue with modding (since the globe is cut to make a rectangle). I say this because setting `res = GeoHistogram[...]` and running `res /. Polygon[pts_List] :> Polygon[pts /. {x_Real, y_} :> {Mod[x, 360, -270], y}]` OR `Show[res, PlotRange -> All]` seem to fix it on my machine.

Comment: @ChipHurst I think `Show` is the best work around yet. Easy to understand and short. Plus it does not break the automatic `GeoCenter` and works with explicit `GeoCenter`.

Comment: @Edmund I'm a bit hesitant to make that an answer because I'm not qualified to know for sure what's happening and why the fix works. If there's no other solution or explanation given, I'll post it as a 'work around' answer.